# iOS Ad hoc distribution - About Apple certificates

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-provisioning, ad-hoc-distribution, provisioning-profile

I want to AdHoc test an application.
My client owns an Apple account and I am member of the team (he added us).

We want to use this technique http://www.innerfence.com/howto/install-iphone-application-ad-hoc-distribution to send the ipa and mobile provision to our client.

The problem is that if I download my client's provisioning profile to generate the ipa it is not paired with any private key in my XCode (valid signed identity not found).

I am completely lost.
How can I fix this?

What I want to do is: generate an .ipa and send it with my client's .mobileprovision file.

Comment: Have you collected your client's UDID and generate a provisioning profile for him & your app?

Comment: No, he created his own provisioning profile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need your client's public/private key pair belonging to their Distribution certificate. The key pair is probably currently only available on the computer that they used to create their certificate.

They will need to perform the following steps to send you their key pair:

1. Open Keychain Access (in /Applications/Utilities)
2. Navigate to 'My Certificates' in the bottom left.
3. They should now see a certificate named 'iPhone Distribution: xxxxxxx', where xxxxxx is the name of their company.
4. Right-click the certificate and select 'Export...'. It should be exported as a Personal Information Exchange (.p12) file and they will have to enter a password to encrypt it.
5. They can now send you this file together with the password. If security is a concern they can e-mail the file to you and give you the password over the phone (for example).
6. On your computer you can simply double-click the .p12 file and voilá you'll now have their certificate and can create the AdHoc build. :)

Good luck!

Comment: Another option instead of using Keychain Access is to use Xcode's Organizer window.  There's an "export developer profile" option that will bundle up the private keys, development/distribution certificates and mobileprovisions in one step.  Then you just copy that to your new mac, and use Xcode's "import developer profile" command to reverse the process.

Comment: I hadn't heard of this before, nice one.