# Certificate added but It shows missing private key

Tags: ios, swift

Right now I'm developing apps on a brand new macbook. I have downloaded the certSigninRequest

[image]

Now I have added both the ios distribution certificate and the private key which is (certSigninRequest)

[image]

But whenever I try to export my app it keeps saying missing private key. I have added to my Keychain already

[image]

Comment: How did you export it? did you select *both* of the files when exporting it?

Comment: I download one from the ios distribution from apple developer website and the private key from my email, and just simply add them

Comment: You have to export it from the current running machine that the certificate is active on it and then use it on the other one(s)...

Comment: You need export the p12 file and import it in your new macbook

Comment: Can I export it on my current machine and click the p12 file again?

Answer (score 9):

For your case, the appropriate way to use the Distribution Certificate to be legal on other machine(s) is to export it from the current machine that uses the certificate.

To do this:

- Navigate the the keychain access.
- Go to the targeted certificate, expand it and select both the certificate and the private key:

[image]

- Right click and select "Export 2 items...".
- Obviously, you should fill the required info, such as the name of the exported file and a password.

The output of the above steps would be a *.p12* file, which should be installed on the other machine(s). Note that revoking the original certificate will also makes this exported file to be invalid.

*Do not* request a new distribution certificate for the new machine, it will automatically revoke the previous one (which leads to make the first machine's certificate to be invalid). This thing is you would generate *only one* Distribution Certificate -by generating a "CertificateSigningRequest" file from the current machine- and then export it to be able to install it on the other machines, which means that all machines use the same distribution certificate.

Also, the following questions might be related to your case:

- [missing private key in the distribution certificate on keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867878/missing-private-key-in-the-distribution-certificate-on-keychain)
- [How can I add private key to the distribution certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563364/how-can-i-add-private-key-to-the-distribution-certificate)